# I'm having a compare issue

Tags: java

I am having a really stupid problem that has been bugging me for a couple of hours now. I have made a program to compare slope of an Array of points and draw a line through four points with the same slope. My problem is I take the initial slope as a comparator to each slope. Then compare the inital value to each other point in the array and if the slope of the initial comparator is the same as the next slope the counter increments. my problem is I done want the initial slope to change during the for loops but I cant get it to work. The code is below, I know im being kind of vague so if you need any more information just ask.

```
 for(int initial = 0; initial < counter/2 ; initial ++)
        {
            int comparator = 1;
            for(int next = 1 ; next < counter/2 ; initial ++)
            {
                Point finalCompare = points[initial];
                Point initialCompare = points[comparator];
                Point initialPoint = points[initial];

                int counter_2 = 0;
                Point nextPoint = points[next];
                double initialSlope = (initialCompare.y - initialPoint.y/ initialCompare.x-initialPoint.x);
                double nextSlope = (nextPoint.y - initialPoint.y/ nextPoint.x - initialPoint.x);


                if(initialSlope == nextSlope)
                {
                    counter_2++;
                    StdOut.println("Counter: " + counter_2);
                    finalCompare = points[next];
                }
                if(counter_2 >= 3)
                {
                    StdOut.println("got here");
                    initialPoint.drawTo(finalCompare);
                    break;
                }
                StdOut.println(counter_2);
            }

            StdOut.println("comparator");
            comparator++;
        }

        }
```

Comment: Side note: writing unit tests would really help you. You can test base cases (like an array of just two points, or three points) and more complicated cases, to isolate where the problem is. Setting breakpoints and using a debugger helps a lot too.

Answer (score 3):

You're never changing `next`. I assume you want

```
for(int next = 1 ; next < counter/2 ; next++)
```

instead of

```
for(int next = 1 ; next < counter/2 ; initial ++)
```

Additionally, this condition seems to never be true: `if(counter_2 >= 3)`

You set `counter_2` to 0 and increment it at most once before this statement:

```
int counter_2 = 0;
...

if(initialSlope == nextSlope)
{
  counter_2++;
  ...
}
//counter_2 can either be 0 or 1 here
if(counter_2 >= 3)
{
  ...
}
```

I assume you want to move the initialization out of the inner loop:

```
int counter_2 = 0;
for(int next = 1 ; next < counter/2 ; next++)
```

Besides that, please step through your code with a debugger and see what is done at each step. This will help you find typing errors (if you understand the algorithm you're implementing, otherwise try and understand that first).

Answer (score 0):

these lines

```
           double initialSlope = (initialCompare.y - initialPoint.y/ initialCompare.x-initialPoint.x);
           double nextSlope = (nextPoint.y - initialPoint.y/ nextPoint.x - initialPoint.x);
```

I think they are not doing what you want, remember that  / has precedence , so first is going to divide initialPoint.y/ initialCompare.x  , and then the rest of the operations,  I think you want to do :

```
   double initialSlope = ((initialCompare.y - initialPoint.y)/ (initialCompare.x-initialPoint.x));
    double nextSlope = ((nextPoint.y - initialPoint.y)/ (nextPoint.x - initialPoint.x));
```